# iOS: Should I always create a custom annotation class for my maps?

Tags: ios, ipad

Should I always create a custom annotation class in order to add an annotation to a map ?

More precisely, do I need to subclass a NSObject implementing MKAnnotation protocol ?

Or is there already an annotation class in SDK, and I can just set latitude and longitude ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MKPlacemark](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008322), [MKPointAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPointAnnotation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009716), [MKCircle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircle_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009710), [MKMultiPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMultiPoint_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009712), [MKPolygon](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolygon_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009717), and [MKPolyline](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009719) classes all implement the MKAnnotation protocol.

MKPointAnnotation is probably the simplest one to use, if you just need to set coordinates.